# Is there a way to read .xlsx files in Applescript using Microsoft Excel scripting without opening the file?

Tags: excel, applescript, xlsx

So I was wondering if I could use the Microsoft Excel scripting in Applescript without opening the actual file. So something like this:

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to return value of cell "E10" of front sheet of "/Path/to/my/file"
```

Comment: I do not have Microsoft Excel, however to get the contents of any file it has to be _read_ and in doing so the _file_ is technically  _opened_, even if not at the GUI level. So in that respect, no you cannot get the contents of a file without it being opened. -- As to can you do as your `code` suggests, I'd say no also.

Comment: @user3439894 Reading .xlsx files is (almost) impossible, at least for me. I'm gonna try it with .csv and maybe post an answer myself.

Comment: xlsx files are a zipped xml and directory structure. If you can figure out how to navigate and read zipped text —presumably there is shell functionality for that— then you could read cell data directly (i.e. without opening excel). Wikipedia has a page on the [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format but if you use an archive viewer you can browse the structure and see for yourself.

Comment: If you don’t wish to use Excel there are XLSX libraries for other languages ([Python](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/), [Node-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xlsx)) that can access .xlsx files directly. (While it is possible to read the underlying XML data yourself, it is very complex and I would not recommend it.)

Comment: A third possibility: install an Objective-C framework [XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter) and call that via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. (Haven’t used it myself so can’t tell you if it’s practical.) However, you never state *why* you don’t want to use Excel (or Numbers), which is the simplest and obvious solution in AppleScript—if you explain that you may get better answers.

Comment: @foo Opening the file kind of defeats the purpose. When working with a relatively small sheet, it's easier to read but the bigger the file gets, the more useful the automation becomes.

Comment: Defeats the purpose of what? The point of using AppleScript is convenience: whipping up a couple lines of AppleScript to control Excel gets the whole job done in *2 minutes flat*. The size of the XLSX is irrelevant: reading a small file is just as complex as reading a large one. As I noted below, I once wrote a very basic XLSX parser for a job where Excel wasn’t available and existing libraries were unsuitable. It took me *days* to learn enough of the spec to write it; many more to get it tested and working reliably with customers’ real-world `.xlsx` files. I really don’t recommend it.

Comment: @foo I asked this question because I was writing a search engine for a spreadsheet. It used the Applescript dialog system. It searched through a very limited base of words (25) and then it returned other information in the same row. I didn't want it to open anything since searching 25 lines by eye isn't that hard but I wanted to know if there even was any way to do it. Thanks to everybody participating, now I know that it's impractical.

Comment: It’s impractical to do it in pure AppleScript. (Not impossible, mind, but a crazy amount of work and excruciatingly slow.) If you’re happy to mix languages a bit, it’s very practical using an existing XLSX reader such as openpyxl (which you can call via `do shell script`, though you may have to install Python first) or XlsxReaderWriter (which you can call via the ASOC bridge). HTH

Answer (score -1):

Reading `.xlsx` files without opening them is very hard or nigh impossible. However, `.csv`-files store their data much more readably. You could set up something like this:

```applescript
set theText to (read file "/Path/to/my/file")
set theLines to paragraphs of theText

return word 6 of (item 10 of theLines)
```

You could also write a function to do the work for you so you don't have to write it out every time:

```applescript
on cell(theColumn, theRow, theTable)
    return word theColumn of item theRow of theTable
end cell

return cell(2, 2, theLines)
```

Here is a bit of a bodgy function I wrote that even takes Excel-style inputs ("E10"):

```applescript
on cell(theLocation, theTable)
    set theChars to every character of theLocation
    set letterPosition to 0
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theChars
        try
            set dummy to item i of theChars as number
            exit repeat
        on error
            set letterPosition to letterPosition + 1
        end try
    end repeat
    if letterPosition is equal to 0 then display dialog "Incorrect input"
    set theRow to items 1 thru letterPosition of theChars
    set theColumn to items (letterPosition + 1) thru (count of theChars) of theChars as string
    set theAlphabet to every character of "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    set theRowNumber to 0
    set theMultiplier to 1
    repeat with j from 1 to count of theRow
        repeat with i from 1 to count of theAlphabet
            if item i of theAlphabet is equal to (item ((count of theRow) - j + 1) of theRow) then
                set theRowNumber to theRowNumber + i * theMultiplier
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        set theMultiplier to theMultiplier * (count of theAlphabet)
    end repeat
    return word theColumn of (item theRowNumber of theTable)
end cell

return cell("AA6", theLines)
```

Yes, I am aware of the `repeat with ... in reverse` but, it somehow didn't work with this function. I have no idea why.

Comment: That code makes a lot of wrong assumptions about CSV structure that will break in real world use. The most obvious flaw is assuming cell contents are single `words`. You neet to split each line on commas (`set text item delimiters to ","`; `text items of aLine`); however that will still fail if any of the cells contain commas themselves, e.g. `1.2,Bob,"Hello, World",3`. It’s not hugely difficult to write a proper parser, but requires some programming knowledge. If you can use a different language, use an existing CSV library. Otherwise, use AppleScript to control Excel or Numbers.